# sap.m.TileContainer scrollIntoView issue

Tags: sapui5

I have an XML view that contains a *TileContainer* which is bound to a model that is used to create *StandardTiles*. The XML snippet is:

```
<TileContainer id="tilelist" tiles="{Applications}">
    <tiles>
        <StandardTile name="{ID}" icon="{Icon}" title="{Name}" press="doNavigation" info="{Description}" 
                          number="{path : 'Number', formatter: 'linxas.com.fiori.launchpad.util.Formatter.formatUsingURL'}" 
                          numberUnit="{NumberUnit}"/>
    </tiles>
</TileContainer>
```

This is working perfectly, the correct tiles are getting displayed etc. When I click on a tile, there is navigation that occurs and I want to "remember" which tile was clicked (by index) so when returning I can scroll to that tile. This is done on the tile's press event handler (`doNavigation` function) and stores the index in `sessionStorage`. This is also working properly.

```
doNavigation : function (evt) {
    if (sessionStorage && this.getView().byId('tilelist')) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("selected_tile", this.getView().byId('tilelist').indexOfTile(evt.getSource()));
    }
    ...
}
```

The proper value is stored. So when navigating back, within the `onAfterRendering` function of the page that contains the *TileContainer* I have the following code. It is attempting to see if there is a "selected_tile" value stored in *sessionStorage*, if so it calls `scollIntoView` passing in the tile index. The issue is that this code is executed, but doesn't work and I suspect it is because at the time of calling this function, the TileContainer's tiles aggregation is returning 0 length.

```
onAfterRendering : function (evt) {
    var theList = this.getView().byId("tilelist");
    if (sessionStorage && theList) {
        var tile_index = sessionStorage.getItem("selected_tile");
        console.log(tile_index + " of " + theList.getTiles().length);
        if (tile_index) {
            theList.scrollIntoView(+tile_index, true);
            sessionStorage.removeItem("selected_tile");
        }
    }
}
```

My console output looks something like this (based on the tile that was clicked):

```
5 of 0
```

Any help would be appreciated. I assume that there is somewhere else that I need to execute this last bit of code as the *TileContainer* does not seem to be finished processing its tiles at this point, at least that is my assumption of why the tiles aggregation is 0.

Comment: IMO, a better approach would be to retrieve the `length` (JSONModel) or `$count` (ODATAModel) of the `Applications` property, and use that instead

Comment: Thanks Qualiture. Unfortunately even though that may give me the size of the data, it does not give me what the TileContainer thinks is it's number of tiles at the time that I am trying to call scrollIntoView. If that number is 0, surely it can't scroll to tile X as it does not yet have that tile. I am suspecting that there is somewhere other than the onAfterRending function of the Page that I need to execute this code, I just don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Routing in your project?
If yes, you can try to register a method to handle the routePatternMatched event of the router. This method will be called after the onAfterRendering method - if the proper route pattern is matched.

To achieve this, just create the following:

```
onInit: function() {
    sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).getRoute("NameOfYourCurrentRoute").attachPatternMatched(this._routePatternMatched, this); 
},
_routePatternMatched: function(oEvent) {
    //do your stuff here
},
```

Hopefully the TileList is ready at this point to navigate to the correct tile.